# Claim warranty on a MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty

I need to know if I can make a warranty claim on a MacBook if there are oxide deposits on its motherboard. I live in a cabana close to the beach, so I am worried.

note: I don't have the Apple Care package with me. But my MacBook is just 8 months old.

Comment: Is something actually wrong with your Mac or are you just curious about a potential hypothetical situation?

Comment: Just curious to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can claim apple care service with out the paper work, all you need is the serial number of the MacBook to verify coverage.

Now if it's cosmetic and not causing any problems with your Mac Book it's  really a judge ment call on Apple if they want to replace it. Contact Apple and non demandingly ask about what they can do about the oxidation.